# Can't run compass after install

Tags: macos, installation, ruby

This is a beginner mistake I am sure as I am new to terminal etc.
I am trying to get [compass](http://compass-style.org/install/) working on my mac, I have already installed sass and got it working but when I try to install compass even though it works I can not run it...

```
computer-name:~ me$ sudo gem install compass
Password:
Successfully installed compass-0.12.2
Parsing documentation for compass-0.12.2
1 gem installed
computer-name:~ me$ compass -v
-bash: compass: command not found
computer-name:~ me$ sass -v
Sass 3.2.12 (Media Mark)
```

Entering:

```
gem list
```

Also returns:

```
compass (0.12.2)
```

Some things I was thinking were maybe I have a conflict, I originally tried to install without `sudo` and it worked, I tried again with `sudo` but it still didn't work.

My $PATH has:

```
computer-name:~ me$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:~/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Users/me/.rvm/bin
```

The last one .rvm/bin seems to be ruby but does not contain compass (although sass is not there either...)

I found compass in `usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.0.0-p247/bin/` but looking at tutorials it seems like it should just run, I am assuming I have done something to break the normal functionality and I would like to know how to test for this or fix it.

*Note: sass is in the same folder and `sass -v` shows the version so I assume it is in the path some how (maybe ruby finds it...)*

Comment: Maybe compass is not in the standard "path" that you can simply invoke from command line? You may need to create a symbolic link to compass from the path, or add compass path into the system path, so you can call 'compass' from anywhere on the system.

Comment: I have looked at the path a little, How would I find compass and add it to the path? I will update my question to include my path.

Comment: Have you restarted your shell already?

Comment: @slhck I had not... but I just did and it still does not work

Comment: @darius also if you look at the link to install compass it seems like after install I should be able to type compass create <project name> and it should work, but it did not. Which is why I think I have done something to my environment...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a very important thing about running two or more versions of Ruby on OS X: If you use `sudo gem`, you will use your OS X default `gem` from `/usr/bin/gem`. This is not what you want.

If you use `gem` alone (without `sudo`), you should normally use newly installed `gem` (e.g. the one from the Ruby OS X installer, or the one from RVM, rbenv, whatever method you used to get another Ruby version running). Confirm this by running `which -a gem`. It should return something like:

```
/Users/your-username/.rvm/bin/gem
/usr/bin/gem
```

If your new `gem` from RVM is not the default (i.e., the first in that list), your RVM installation is broken. Otherwise any call to `gem`, even without `sudo`, will still use the `/usr/bin/gem` and subsequently fail due to insufficient permissions.

So, make sure that all calls to `ruby` and `gem` are the RVM versions, and not the system ones. And *never* use `sudo` again to install something, because it'll land in your default OS X Ruby.

For RVM specifically, check that it is sourced *after* all your PATH manipulations are done in the shell's configuration file (usually `.profile` or `.bash_profile` on OS X, not sure which one RVM modifies).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, `watch` returned `/usr/local/bin/gem /usr/bin/gem /usr/local/bin/gem` (I guess the last is a little redundant..) The first in local is a link to `/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.0.0-p247/bin/gem` so it should work (and it does show up in ruby without sudo, it just does not work on its own.

Comment: I added an answer with more details but voted yours as you gave good advice, I think I need to wipe my hard disc and start over :)

Comment: I understand the no `sudo` thing, but far out - the SASS project says to use it, and that's a fairly official starting point for a lot of people: http://sass-lang.com/install

Answer (score 4):

I experienced the same thing. This is what I did to get the compass command working: I added a symbolic link (I have .12.6, changed it to your .12.2):

```
ln -s /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-0.12.2/bin/compass /usr/local/bin/compass
```

Comment: Looks like a workaround but its works.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem and found that `gem list compass -d` allowed me to find and symlink compass.

Answer (score 1):

I don't feel this is really an answer to my question but at the moment it works...
I found compass in my system at `/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-0.12.2/bin/` so I added that to `~/.bash_profile` at the beginning of `export PATH="<here>:/usr/local/bin:other paths"`
so now I can run the function but I still don't know how to diagnose the system and find the cause of the problem or fix it so It feels like a hack.

I got some useful info from [here (stackoverflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9828864/ruby-version-manager-broke-my-path), [here (apple.stackoverflow)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/91381/how-can-i-reset-my-terminal) and [the ruby rvm help site](https://rvm.io/support/faq#shell_login)